# Rename relation name when auto fetching in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
    class Order extends Elequent{
        protected $table = 'order';
        const CREATED_AT = "createdAt";
        const UPDATED_AT = "updatedAt";

        protected $with = array('orderItem', 'address');
        public function orderItem(){
            return $this->hasMany("OrderItem","orderId");
        }
        public function address(){
            return $this->hasOne("OrderAddress","orderId","id");
        }
    }

    //in controller
    $order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);
    echo $order;
```

When serialize the order  to json using above class,how can I make the order_item to orderItem(I like camel case more than snake case)

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "userId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2015-04-30 12:08:26",
  "deletedAt": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "updatedAt": "2015-04-30 12:08:26",
  "state": "activated",
  "deliveryNote": null,
  "order_item": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "specialProductId": 29,
      "volume": 750,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": "543.38",
      "orderId": 1,
      "updatedAt": "2015-04-30 12:08:26",
      "createdAt": "2015-04-30 12:08:26"
    }
  ],
  "address": null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy/rename the object property and unset the old one.

```
//in controller

$order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);

$order->orderItem = $order->order_item;
unset($order->order_item);

echo $order;
```

For better usage, you can put this method on your Base model,

```
public function toArrayCamel()
{
    $array = $this->toArray();

    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $return[camel_case($key)] = $value;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

and later on your controller,

```
$order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);

return Response::json( $order->toArrayCamel() );
```

Comment: it is pretty good way for one fields,but I want the solution can be apply to multiple items in array ,I will check the documentation and then update this question.thanks.

Comment: @Phlip Thank you.That works well.In fact,I am going to write a function to make the toArrayCamel recurrsive so that the relation inside a field can also become camel.

Answer (score 13):

In your model, set the `$snakeAttributes` property to false. This will keep the attributes from being snake_cased when generating the array.

```
class Order extends Elequent {

    public static $snakeAttributes = false;

}
```